# Can someone please explain the following code?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to understand the idea of **objects in an array**, & in the book (*from which I am learning*) following code is given as an example. I am having difficulty to understand it.

```
public class Mix4
{
  int counter = 0;
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int count = 0;
    Mix4[] m4a = new Mix4[20];
    int x = 0;
    while(x<19)
    {
      m4a[x] = new Mix4();
      m4a[x].counter = m4a[x].counter+1;
      count = count+1;
      count = count+m4a[x].maybeNew(x);
      x = x+1;
    }
    System.out.println(count+" "+m4a[1].counter);
   }

   public int maybeNew(int index)
   {
     if(index<1)
     {
       Mix4 m4 = new Mix4();
       m4.counter = m4.counter+1;
       return 1;
     }
     return 0;
   }
 }
```

Following is the output:-

> 20 1

Also, please explain **how objects in an array behave?**

Comment: Specifically which part do you have difficulty to understand?

Comment: In exactly what point you found difficulty to understand ?

Comment: That code is in a book?

Comment: If you pasted the code correctly, I'd suggest to look for better books

Comment: I am having difficulty in while loop and in if statement. Like in if statement they are writing  "m4.counter=m4.counter+1;"

Comment: That just increases the value of counter for m4. Since m4 is a newly created object that is not used again this has no effect on the printed result. I assume this is deliberately badly written code used as an exercise to test your ability to follow code.

Comment: horrible title for a question. be specific

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding that code as well. There's a lot of nonsense in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to start off by saying that this is very poorly written code and I do not blame you for being confused. 
This program starts off by creating an array of Mix4 objects. Then it has a while loop. The while loop is poorly written because the objective is to loop through every element of the array. But if you want to change the amount of objects in the array you have to also change the loop. A better way to do this is:

```
for(int x =0; x< m4a.length -1; x++) {
    //Code
}
```

The loop then adds one to the counter of the Max4 object. Then is has a count variable that increments by one every iteration of the loop
It then calls the maybeNew method. This method takes an input, checks if it is less than zero, and if so, it creates an Max4 object that is never used again, increments the new objects counter variable, and then simply returns 1. If it is one or more it just returns 0. (By the way, a method should only have one return statement.)

The while loop then increments x and the while loop will iterate 20 times. After the while loop finishes, the program prints out how many times the loop incremented and then the counter of the Max4 object in the first index of the array.

As to your question about how objects behave in arrays, they behave just like they would if they were not in an array. Just like integers behave the same whether they are in an array or not. An array is simply a data structure that allows for efficient processing of the objects.